# ANTLR4 Error : Missing NEWLINE

Tags: antlr4

```
grammar Hello;          
prog:   stat+ EOF;
stat:   expr NEWLINE    # printExpr 
|   ID '=' expr NEWLINE # assign
|   NEWLINE     # blank 
|   STRING NEWLINE  # string
;
expr:   expr (MUL|DIV) expr # opExpr
|   expr (ADD|SUB) expr # opExpr
|   expr AND expr # andExpr
|   INT         # int
|   ID          # id
|   '(' expr ')'        # parens
;
MUL:    '*';
DIV:    '/';
ADD:    '+';
SUB:    '-';
ID: [a-zA-Z]+[0-9a-zA-Z]*;
NEWLINE : [\r\n] ;
INT     : [0-9]+ ;
AND :     '&';
WS  : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
CM  : '//' ~[\r\n]* -> skip;`
```

Can someone explain to me what is wrong with my code? This is my error :

[image: error]

Your help will be appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in these lexer rules:

```
NEWLINE : [\r\n] ;
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

When the lexer finds a `\r\n` in the input string, it will try to match the rules, and both will match. However, `WS` will match the entire `\r\n`, producing one `WS` token, and `NEWLINE` will match `\r` then `\n`, producing two `NEWLINE` tokens.

In this scenario, Antlr always chooses the longest match, in your case it will produce `WS`. If you look at your lexer output for `a = 3\r\nx = 4\r\n`, the generated tokens will be:

```
ID WS '=' WS INT WS    ID WS '=' WS INT WS
a      =      3 \r\n   x      =     4   \r\n
```

But what you're looking for is:

```
ID WS '=' WS INT NEWLINE ID WS '=' WS INT NEWLINE
a      =      3  \r\n    x      =     4   \r\n
```

---

Your grammar seems to be written entirely expecting all the line breaks to generate `NEWLINE` tokens, so I suggest changing the `WS` rule to:

```
WS: [ \t]+ -> skip;
```